# Could we form commands with "we, he, she, it, they & you don't": "we/they do it", "he/she open the door", "You don't do it"?

Tags: word-usage, tense, phrase-usage, phrase-request, imperative-sentences

[According to Cambridge grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/imperative-clauses-be-quiet)

> We use imperative clauses when we want to tell someone to do something
>   (most commonly for advice, suggestions, requests, commands, orders or
>   instructions).
>
> We can use them to tell people to do or not to do things. They usually
>   don’t have a subject – they are addressed to the listener or
>   listeners, who the speaker understands to be the subject. We use the
>   base form of the verb:
>
> Have fun.
>
> Enjoy your meal.
>
> Stop talking and open your books.
>
> For emphasis, we can use you in an imperative clause:
>
> [a student and a teacher]
>
> A: Can I leave the room?
>
> B: No. **You stay** here.
>
> In negative imperatives of this type, **you comes after don’t**:
>
> Maria, **don’t you try to pay for this**. I invited you for lunch and I
>   insist on paying.
>
> We can also use words like someone, somebody, no one, nobody,
>   everyone, everybody, especially in speaking:
>
> **Somebody call** a doctor. Quick!
>
> **Everybody sit down**, please.

So, we often form commands with "**you**", "**somebody**" or "**everybody**", etc, for example, "**You close the door**", "**Somebody call a doctor**", "**Everybody sit down**".

But, Could we form commands with "**we, he, she, it, they**", for example, "**we/they do it**", "**he/she open the door**" (no "**s**" after "**open**" because it's not the simple present)?

And, could we form negative commands with "**you don't**", for example, "**you don't open the door**"?

Comment: I find this question to be somewhat obnoxious. And if you language is not English, I'm sure that's true in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

**We**
You can't command yourself to do something. You can merely state an intention, as in **we shall do it**.

**You**
It's most unusual to begin a command with **you**. Rather than **You don't open the door** we would generally just say **Don't open the door**. The **you** is understood. It's possible to construct a scene in which three or more people are involved. A teacher might say to a pupil: **You don't open the door; let him do it**. But the teacher would be far more likely to use first names: **John don't open the door; let Michael do it**.

But it's common to use **you** in front of advice. **You shouldn't open the door as the wind will cover the room with dust**. **You don't do it this way**.

**He, she & they**
Here you can construct indirect instructions: **He/she/they must remain behind**.
But you can't address someone as **he** or **she** in the imperative.

**Somebody, everybody & nobody**
There's no problem using these in the imperative, as you indicate.
**Nobody move** and **everybody freeze** are classic bank robber lines!

Comment: In the movie "Star wars: the rise of skywalker", there is a scene, the bad guys on a motorbike are chasing the good guys & suddenly the bad guys flied in the air & the good guys say "They fly now". So, is it a command?

Comment: @Tom That's a *description*. No command is being communicated to them. On the other hand, you're close. It's possible for *We fly now!* to be considered an imperative. It's uncommon, but it exists. (It's not normal to think of you giving commands to yourself. But the intention and syntax can warrant that interpretation.)

Comment: I think this question is a take-the-piss question, really. I would not dignify it with an answer.